# Generic repository split LINQ Expression between contexts

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, repository-pattern, linq-expressions

If you have two `DbContext`s and say `EntityOne` belongs to `DbContextOne` and `EntityTwo` belongs to `DbContextTwo`.

How can I create a generic repository abstraction that execute `EntityOne` query and `EntityTwo` query in their respective contexts, hydrate them to memory and reconcile the results?

Is there a prior work that I can use as reference/guide?

Comment: you want an example of a generic repository that can serve for both of the dbcontexts?

Comment: No, I want a generic repository that allows me to operate (eg. `Join()`) on entities from 2 distinct db contexts. By splitting execution of the query expression and delegating them appropriately. The client should be completely Persistent Ignorant.

Comment: If you need to join, then consider using a single context.  At the moment, these entities seem to be more related than your design allows.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a generic repository abstraction that execute EntityOne query and EntityTwo query in their respective contexts, hydrate them to memory and reconcile the results?

Simple. Do not create a generic repository. Create a specific one. Just take the two other repositories in the constructor.